# Angular/Ionic expression call

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an array of ISODate ( from the database ), i did a refactor so i can get the date in the format i want, my problem is i don't know how to call it in the view side.

```
 <div class="message-date">{{ party.date }}</div>
```

This is displaying me

```
Thu Jul 12 2018 09:39:08 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

party is a document in the database with the field date

I did this in my ts file so i can get the right format

```
const test = this.party.map(a => a.date);
console.log(test)

/// Will Display 
["Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
  "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
  "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:21:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
  "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:03:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
  "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:01:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
  "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:53:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
  "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:52:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
  "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
  "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
  "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
]
```

This is what i want to display on my view side

```
const test1 = test.map(a => new Date(a).toLocaleString(locale, options))
    console.log(test1)
/// will display

 [
  "Monday 16 July 2018",
  "Friday 13 July 2018",
  "Friday 13 July 2018",
  "Friday 13 July 2018",
  "Friday 13 July 2018",
  "Friday 13 July 2018",
  "Friday 13 July 2018",
  "Thursday 12 July 2018",
  "Thursday 12 July 2018",
  "Thursday 12 July 2018"
]
```

So instead of displaying on my view the first one i want to display the second format of the date, didn't know how to call it ?

I need to modify something here

```
 <div class="message-date">{{ party.date }}</div>
```

and call test1.??? instead of party.date

Comment: Have a look at the Angular Date Pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe
Change `{{party.date}}` to `{{party.date | date}}` and there you go.

Comment: @D.Simon This is not working, i'm using Ionic Sorry .

Comment: Is there a way to call the test ?

Comment: It's working thank you